# JQ, two queries, over different part of json, Merge it back

Tags: jq, kubectl

I am trying to extract kubeconfig data with jq.

`kubectl config view --raw -o json | jq ...`

There is a json produced of this kind:

```
{
    "kind": "Config",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "preferences": {},
    "clusters": [
        {
            "name": "some-name",
            "cluster": {
                "server": "https://some-url",
                "certificate-authority-data": "some-cert"
            }
        },
      {
          "name": "another-name",
          "cluster": {
              "server": "https://another-url",
              "certificate-authority-data": "another-cert"
          }
      }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "some-name",
            "user": {
                "username": "some-user",
                "password": "some-password"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "another-name",
            "user": {
                "username": "another-user",
                "password": "another-password"
            }
        }
    ],
    "contexts": [],
    "current-context": "some-context"
}
```

**Question #1:**
For a given name ,"some-name", I'd like to extract json:

```
{
  url: "https://some-url",
  cert: "some-cert",
  username: "some-user",
  password: "some-password"
}
```

**Question #2:**
"users" sub-section can have other format

```
"users": [
    {
        "name": "...",
        "user": {
            "exec": {
                ...
            }
```

Where `.user.username` or `.user.password` or both can be missing

In this case overall query should return "{}", even though, "clusters" query/branch has result

---

**Question 3**, as a follow up to Jeff Mercado answer:

I want to get all clusters, joined (grouped by) name:

Looking at the manual, https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions ,

section "Multiplication, division, modulo: *, /, and %", example:

```
jq '{"k": {"a": 1, "b": 2}} * {"k": {"a": 0,"c": 3}}' => {"k": {"a": 0, "b": 2, "c": 3}}'
```

gives presumably right result, assuming "k" is value of "name". So, grouping by "k", merging (*) the results.

I produced following query:

```
echo "${json}" | jq -r  '(.clusters[] | {(.name): {url: .cluster.server, cert: .cluster["certificate-authority-data"]}}) * (.users[] | {(.name): {user: .user.username, password: .user.password}})'
```

First part returns {"name": {url: cert}}, second part is {"name": {username, password}}
However, result is not merge as in jq Manual, but something else ... product ?

```
{
  "some-name": {
    "url": "https://some-url",
    "cert": "some-cert",
    "user": "some-user",
    "password": "some-password"
  }
}
{
  "another-name": {
    "url": "https://another-url",
    "cert": "another-cert"
  },
  "some-name": {
    "user": "some-user",
    "password": "some-password"
  }
}
{
  "some-name": {
    "url": "https://some-url",
    "cert": "some-cert"
  },
  "another-name": {
    "user": "another-user",
    "password": "another-password"
  }
}
{
  "another-name": {
    "url": "https://another-url",
    "cert": "another-cert",
    "user": "another-user",
    "password": "another-password"
  }
}
```

Why/what is it ? Kind of following idea of the product ('*') but not of the jq tutorial as I (most likely, incorrectly) understand it

---

**Experimentation:**
I have 2 queries now producing partial result.

Let's grab original json (above) in and parse:

```
read -d '' json << EOF
...
EOF
```

queries:

```
echo "${json}" | jq -r '.clusters[] | select(.name=="some-name") | .cluster | {url: .server, cert: .["certificate-authority-data"]}' &&\
echo "${json}" | jq -r '.users[] | select(.name=="some-name") | .user | {user: .username, password: .password}'
```

Will produce the split output:

```
{
  "url": "https://some-url",
  "cert": "some-cert"
}
{
  "user": "some-user",
  "password": "some-password"
}
```

Or, with key added for further merge:

```
echo "${json}" | jq -r '.clusters[] | select(.name=="some-name") | {name: .name, url: .cluster.server, cert: .cluster["certificate-authority-data"]}' &&\
echo "${json}" | jq -r '.users[] | select(.name=="some-name") | {name: .name, user: .user.username, password: .user.password}'
```

Will produce:

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "url": "https://some-url",
  "cert": "some-cert"
}
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "user": "some-user",
  "password": "some-password"
}
```

"name" is not needed but can be used as a join operation

Answer (score 6):

So you already know how to get the cluster and user by name separately, first step is to select them both within a single filter:

```
(.clusters[] | select(.name == $name).cluster), (.users[] | select(.name == $name).user)
```

This will yield two separate objects, the cluster, then the user. But we want to merge them. There's plenty of ways to do this. You could add them (`+`) directly or merge them (`*`) but no real difference there. You'll just want to remap the properties to the names you wanted where needed.

```
(.clusters[] | select(.name == $name).cluster | {url: .server, cert: ."certificate-authority-data"})
+
(.users[] | select(.name == $name).user | {username, password})
```

Pass the name in as a parameter to your filter;

```
$ kubectl config view --raw -o json | jq --arg name some-name '
(.clusters[] | select(.name == $name).cluster | {url: .server, cert: ."certificate-authority-data"})
+
(.users[] | select(.name == $name).user | {username, password})
'
```

---

For the second part of your question, if it turns out the mapped user is missing key properties and you want to omit them, just add another `select` filter to the end to test for those properties and replace with an empty object if nothing is found:

```
... | select(has("username") and has("password")) // {}
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/u_1_YzGgWC)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly, what I needed. Besides directions to the topics to read in jq manual